# System.ObjectDisposedException in ILGenerated method

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, delegates, opcode

I add to ILGenerator strings

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, readField);
```

and

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _read.GetMethodInfo());
```

into base code

```
private ReadItemDelegate _read;

    /// <summary>
    /// Init Get method of instance
    /// </summary>
    private void InitGetMethod()
    {
        var ti = typeof (int);
        Type[] methodArgs2 = { _globalType, ti, ti, ti, ti, ti, ti, ti, ti, ti, ti };// 10 elements

        #region this.Get = double(int, .., int) { return _shift0[i0] + .. + _shiftn[in] }
        var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("", ChildrenType, methodArgs2, _globalType);// create dynmic method

        var ilGen = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        var fiShift = new FieldInfo[_dims.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < _dims.Length; i++) // get links to all shift arrays
        {
            fiShift[i] = _globalType.GetField("_shift" + i, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        }

        var ldargs = new[] {OpCodes.Ldarg_1, OpCodes.Ldarg_2, OpCodes.Ldarg_3};

        var readField = _globalType.GetField("_read", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (readField == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("_read");

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, readField);

        for (var i = 0; i < _dims.Length; i++)
        {

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //push link to class member 
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fiShift[i]); //push link to shift array
            if (i < 3) // push next param
                ilGen.Emit(ldargs[i]);
            else
                ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, i+1);

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_I8); // pop 3 vars and push value from our array by param as index. Result as I8

            if (i>0) ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Add); // pop 2 vars, summ and push back

        }

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _read.GetMethodInfo());

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Get = (GetItemDelegate) dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate( typeof(GetItemDelegate), this); // save method as Get variable
        #endregion
    }
```

when i try use

```
this.Get(1,2,3)
```

i got this error, but when i use

```
this._read(2568)
```

I get the correct result.

**Where in the code can be a bug?**

**Anyone who tries to help thanks in advance.**

Here is shortener example to explain bug:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class test
    {

        public delegate double GetItemDelegate(int i0 = 0, int i1 = 0, int i2 = 0);
        public delegate double ReadItemDelegate(Int64 offset);


        Type _globalType = typeof(test);
        Type ChildrenType = typeof(double);

        public GetItemDelegate Get;
        private ReadItemDelegate _read;

        public test()
        {
            var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("file", 123);
            var readMethod = typeof(MemoryMappedViewAccessor).GetMethod("ReadDouble");
            var viewAccessor = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 123);
            _read = (ReadItemDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ReadItemDelegate), viewAccessor, readMethod);


            var ti = typeof(int);
            Type[] methodArgs2 = { _globalType, ti, ti, ti };// 10 elements

            var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("", ChildrenType, methodArgs2, _globalType);// create dynmic method
            var ilGen = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();


            var readField = _globalType.GetField("_read", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, readField);

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 3214);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _read.GetMethodInfo());

            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            Get = (GetItemDelegate)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetItemDelegate), this); // save method as Get variable
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tmp = new test();

            Console.WriteLine(tmp.Get());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `this.Get(1,2,3)` and `this._read(2568)`? which is the generated method? What does `GetItemDelegate` look like? Basically: how can we repro this? How come the method has 10 parameters, but your two examples: don't? What is `_dims`, and how large is it? What are the `_shift` fields? Basically, I think it is entirely unanswerable in the current state.

Comment: I do rather suspect, however, that if you run this through [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/), you'll get a more useful error message

Comment: code  `for (var i = 0; i < _dims.Length; i++) {...}` works fine. When method get 1,2,3 as parameters this loop pushes 2568 in stack. I try to use it as a parameter to delegate method "_read". need any more explanation?

Comment: Yes.... you see all those questions I asked? Basically: you should try to reduce this down to a reproducible example that people here can *actually run* to see the problem. There's a good chance that in doing so: you will find the problem; but if you don't, there's a good chance that people here (like myself) would be able to do so.

Comment: ok, i ll try to get reproducible example.

Comment: also - when you do, if you add a comment here with @Marc in it, I'll get a notification; otherwise, I might not see it

Comment: hi, @MarcGravell shortener example if first post

Comment: @Marc or so to send a message?

Comment: Thanks; I'll have a look at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example in the edit: the issue is as simple as an incorrect field access and method call; look here:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, readField);

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 3214);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _read.GetMethodInfo());
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Here, `_read` is a delegate to `viewAccessor.ReadDouble` - i.e. `ReadDouble` is the instance method, and `viewAccessor` is the target instance. We have two options:

- invoke `ReadDouble` against the instance we stored previously in `viewAccessor`
- invoke `Invoke` on the delegate

The second of these we could do by something like:

```
// removed: ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _read.GetMethodInfo());
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, _read.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"));
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Note that you'll have to use a value other than `3214`, or change the capacity / size of the file / view-accessor to something bigger than `123`.

However, it would probably be more efficient to forget about `_read`, and store the `viewAccessor` instead, and call-virt `readMethod`. For example:

```
private MemoryMappedViewAccessor _acc;

// ...

var viewAccessor = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 123 * 1000);
_acc = viewAccessor; 
var accField = _globalType.GetField("_acc",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

// ...

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, accField);

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 3214);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8);

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, readMethod);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The numbers `123` and `3214` were randomly selected, solely to run the example of the previous error.